# Possible to use Windows installation of Anaconda in WSL2?

Tags: anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

And if so, how to do this?

I've only found instructions on installing anaconda through WSL2 but I already have it installed in Windows.

I found the below snippet to have WSL2 run my windows bash helper that stored my github credentials and was hoping for something similar.

`git config --global credential.helper "/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-manager.exe"`

Or if I have to install through WSL2 but can use that in Windows that would be fine too. I just would really prefer not to have 2 copies of it.